# Apply blur effect on tap or selected area if UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a simple setup:

UIViewController->UIView->UIImageView

I want to achieve blur on UIImage which is loaded in UIImageView **only on the area that user select or tap or move the finger**.

Is it possible using UIVisualEffectView?

Comment: @YunCHEN not duplicate. Creating blur effect on image is different thing and adding blur when user tap on area/selection is different thing

Comment: try this :- https://github.com/nfscan/ios-blur-pan-gesture